# binary opposite number

Tags: algorithm, math, binary, bit

I want to get the opposite number of binary number (means x--> -(x) and -(x) --> x).

What will be the algorithm ? I thought about change all bits ("1" to "0" and "0" to "1") and add "1" to it. Is it OK ?

thnx

Comment: You could google that: http://www.math.grin.edu/~rebelsky/Courses/152/97F/Readings/student-binary#neg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your algorithm is correct for two's complement numbers:

```
-x = ~x + 1
```

For one's complement, you'd use:

```
-x = ~x
```

And for sign-magnitude numbers:

```
-x = x ^ (1 << n)
```

Where `n` is the offset of the sign bit in the word.  I am using C operator notation here - `^` is the bitwise exclusive-or operator, and `<<` is a left-shift.

For another number representation, you'd need to use some other operation.

Comment: Can you provide me with a better algorithm ?
thnx

Comment: @Adam D - there is no "better algorithm".  In any reasonable language you could just write `-x`, so why do anything other than that?

Comment: Its for MIPS program I am writing that change a number in $s0 to its opposite, I know how to write it in C etc. how to do so, but is there a better way in MIPS assembly to do so ?

Comment: @Adam D, doesn't MIPS have a register that's always zero?  You could just do `sub $s0, $0, $s0` then, right?

Comment: my problem is that the number (on purpose) stored at $s0 LOL :) so how about: not $s0 , $s0 and then: addi $s0 , $s0 , 1 is this sounds good ?

Comment: @Adam, yes that's fine.  I just tried the `sub` example I gave above, and it works fine here in SPIM.  That's one instruction instead of two, whatever turns your crank I guess!

Comment: Can you write down the exact sub order in this case ? tnx

Comment: You meant sub $s0, $s0 , $s0 or as you wrote above ?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the way negative numbers are represented. You need two's complement representation? You need one's complement representation?

For more details check [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement#Ones.27_complement)

Comment: Actually its for a MIPS assembly program I am writing that change a number in $s0 to its opposite, then what will be better ?

Comment: Why not simply do $s0 = 0 - $s0. Then you don't have to worry about the way the negative numbers are represented. You will know for sure that your result is the correct one, no matter what your processor architecture is.